# Visual Studio 2008 complains about trusted locations. What to do?

Tags: visual-studio, security, assemblies

I was messing around with [RhinoMocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) this morning and couldn't run my tests because RhinoMocks.dll was not in a "trusted location". The assembly is in my c:\documents and settings\\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects (and so on) folder. What's the deal?

Comment: Hey, Nick answered the question correctly; you should mark his response as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download a zip file from the internet and then extract it using the standard explorer tools. I think this marks the directory as untrusted and Visual studio detects this.

Comment: Nick, that was indeed the problem. I figured it would be useful to post the question so I could also put the answer there. I hadn't counted on someone answering so quickly!

Comment: So how do you re-trust it?  "Unblock" does not appear in my explorer context menu.

Answer (score 1):

From my reading, there are a number of things that can cause this. The fix for my particular situation, however, was to "unblock" the DLL file. Because I had downloaded the zip from the Internet, XP had put a block on the file. Right-clicking the file and clicking "Unblock" did the trick.

Comment: ok,  but what happens when I have 1000 files in that zip? Clicking "Unblock" for two weeks is not my ideea of fun.

Comment: You can unblock the zip file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file or location and choose Properties. At the very bottom, you should see the button "Unblock". Click it and press OK.